# Remove items from list using their IDs and linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List` of "widget"s (which have an int ID), and a `List` of selected IDs. My end goal is to have a List of hydrated widgets that agrees with the ID list inside my "set".

```
public List<Widget> widgets { get; set; }

public List<int> widgetIds
{
    get
    {
        return widgets.Select(x => x.widgetId).ToList();
    }
    set
    {
        foreach (int addId in value.Except(widgets.Select(x => x.widgetId)))
        {
            widgets.Add(_dbWidgetHelper.getWidget(addId));
        }

        //I need to invert the add somehow
    }
}
```

I've been trying everything I can think of using `RemoveAll` and `Except`, but I can't wrap my head around the solution yet. I know this can be done in one line, but the closest I've got is:

```
var removeIds = widgets.Select(x => x.widgetId).Except(value);

//this is me trying anything I can think of... obviously a syntax error.
widgets.RemoveAll(x=>x.widgetId in removeIds);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.  Note that I changed `removeIds` to be a `HashSet<int>` to prevent the query from being re-evaluated every time and to make the look up faster

```
var removeIds = new HashSet<int>(widgets.Select(x => x.widgetId).Except(value));

widgets.RemoveAll(x => removeIds.Contains(x.widgetID));
```

Comment: can this be merged into a 1-liner? is it worth it performance/readability -wise?

Comment: OK, I looked at `widgets.RemoveAll(x => widgets.Select(y => y.widgetId).Except(value).Contains(x.widgetId));` and it instantly gave me a headache, so I'll say it fails the readability test.